# Is it necessary to synchronize a factory method that returns a new instance of a class in java

Tags: java, factory

Today i was asked to write up a factory to get a new instance of a class.
I did this quite easily.

One of my all knowing colleagues looked at my code and told me to synchronize the method that does this.

I asked him why and he replied that is the right thing to do. (offered no explanation when asked) I did not do it as i believe since i'm not manipulating the state of the object, i don't have to synchronize it.

I just want to clarify whether i was right. If i was wrong, can someone explain why it is necessary to synchronize.

eg

```
private static Map<String, IProduct> products = new HashMap<String, IProduct>();

public IProduct getInstance(code){
   return products.get(code).create();
}
```

**Edit based on comments :**

- I can't give the full code as I don't have access to it now. I will do it when I get back to work.
- products is a `Map<String, IProduct>`
- `create()` is a method on the class implementing `IProduct`. This method just returns a new instance of the implementing class.
- the instance put into the static map is only to be used to 'new' up an instance of `Product`.

Comment: What is `products`, and what is the `???.create()` method?

Comment: If you indeed don't mutate any state this won't be necessary, but we won't know until you show us the real code. By the way congratulations on not listening to your "all knowing" colleague without using your own brain. An engineer should be able to back every statement he makes with sensible arguments

Comment: Can you post the whole class? It will be easier to judge if synchronization is necessary.

Comment: There are several ways this method could be potentially not thread-safe (depending mostly on what happens to `products` in parts of the code you haven't posted), but most of them wouldn't be solved by making just this one method `synhronized`. It's impossible to give a straightforward answer with just the code you've given us, but the assumption that "since i'm not manipulating the state of the object, i don't have to synchronize it" is definitely wrong in general.

Comment: @biziclop in a purely immutable world, every operation is thread-safe, so I disagree with your last statement

Comment: @Dici But the statement "I'm not manipulating state == I don't need synchronization" *is* wrong in general as nothing in the question suggests "a purely immutable world".

Comment: @DaveNewton what difference do you make between immutability and not modifying the state ?

Comment: @Dici The distinction I make is that the OP suggests nothing about any other aspects of the system in question, nor have I seen a response addressing your, or biziclop's, questions. I'm focusing on what the OP is asking, not your hypothetical.

Comment: @DaveNewton ok, just a matter of interpretation then because to be it just meant no object used by this class was mutated in any way, and it seems to be the case based on the latest edit (private static map, supposedly not mutated within this class, so never mutated)

Comment: Yes, the way I interpreted it is that "**I**don't mutate state, but someone else somewhere may". And it is an often held misconception that only writes need to be synchronized, concurrent reads will be fine. But obviously if no-one ever will mutate the state, that's a different story altogether.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess that `products` is a `Map` and that it is not synchronized (either by its implementation or via `Collections.syncronizedMap()`). If whatever is stored in `products` is mutable, then it is possible that something else is going to be working with `products` while you are using `get()` and this could cause some issue.

Specifically, if whatever the class is that has a `create()` method is mutable, then in a parallel environment, some other thread could mutate the value retrieved from `products` after `get()` and before `create()`, which *could* cause problems (for instance, if `create()` can only be called a set number of times).

That said, you should press your colleague as to why they want you to synchronize the method. They should have a specific reason, and if they can't explain it to you, their reason either isn't good enough or they don't understand it enough.

Answer (score -3):

If we synchronize the factory method,we will make sure while one thread retrieves a new instance,any other thread does not do the same.Instead any parallel thread would wait for its turn and get the already created instance.

Comment: This is not answering to the question, asking if it is **necessary**. And we can't anwer, since we don't have the code

Comment: Since I was not sure what exactly you want to achieve with your code, I just wanted to put forward what you might achieve if you make it synchronous.